# Clear Firebase persistence Indexed DB after logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing authentication to react using firebase.

I am facing an issue when logging out, and then logging in again with another user credentials. Firebase is keeping the access token and the user information of the first user.

I tried to clear IndexedDB manually but it didn't work.

**Login Implementation:**

```js
Firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  .then(() => Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((response) => {
    //impl
    return response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  }));
```

**Logout Implementation:**

```js
export async function logoutFirebase() {
  indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb');
  return Firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

Comment: When you run this code, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: this line //indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb'); @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Calling `signOut` should be sufficient to clear the stored credential from `indexedDB`. You don't need to explicitly delete the database.

Comment: @bojeil yes. explicitly deleting it was the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after switching from persisting the user from **firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION** to **firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL**, I had to remove this line completely:

```js
indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb');
```

Since it interferes with firebase by purging the IndexedDB.

When you log in with the second user, the auth is not persisted at all.
You have either to force refresh the login page in order for firebase to initialize IndexedDB again, or get rid of that line completely, which is the best choice of course.

Comment: Can cause issues when same user is open in multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the authentication persistence is set to Local, you need clear out 3rd party cookies to sign-out.

Try this :

```
export function logoutFirebase() {
    return Firebase.auth().signOut()
        .then(() => {
            deleteAllCookies();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("sign out failed", error));
}

function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right about the cookie part since i am storing some user informations in it, but i have managed by removing indexedDB.deleteDatabase("firebaseLocalStorageDb"); compleatly @Melchia